# MIPS, Addition of double precision floating points, getting incorrect result

Tags: assembly, floating-point, mips

I'm writing a MIPS program that allocates two or more multidimensional arrays of double precision float and add them together, but it seems I didn't understand the concept of addition of double precision float.

I already know I have to use even $f registers when working with double precision, I wrote this simple program and I don't understand why it doesn't work correctly.

```
    .text
main:
li  $v0,6 # getting first number
syscall
mov.d   $f4,$f0

mov.d   $f12,$f4
li  $v0,2
syscall
li  $a0,10 # new line
li  $v0,11
syscall

li  $v0,6 # getting second number
syscall
mov.d   $f6,$f0

mov.d   $f12,$f6
li  $v0,2
syscall
li  $a0,10 # new line
li  $v0,11
syscall

add.d   $f12,$f4,$f6 # add them together and show the result
li  $v0,2
syscall

li  $v0,10
syscall
    .data
```

sample run:

```
**** user input : 1.22
1.22
**** user input : 4.66
4.66
-4.525653E-39
-- program is finished running --
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do your `syscall` calls preserve the values in `$f4` and `$f6`?

Comment: @GregHewgill  Yes. I just checked the values in $f4 and $f6 are correct. there should be something wrong with my add.d and I don't understand what is that.

Comment: Can you also check the value in `$f12` after the `add.d` instruction? Checking that will at least let you know whether the problem is in the adding, or in the output.

Comment: @GregHewgill I checked problem isn't from output, it is from addition.please look at my screen shots. http://s24.postimg.org/dp8uni4lx/image.png  http://s18.postimg.org/56af6s6dl/image.png   http://s8.postimg.org/fj1haisn9/image.png

Comment: Ok, so try it with simpler input where the numbers are obvious: 1 + 2 = ?

Comment: @GregHewgill I'm getting infinity (1.#INF0000)

Comment: The screen shots seem to be about 32 bit floats. Why?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Those screen shots are from MARS 4.3, I don't know why but It was able to show double precision for $f4 and $f6 correctly, but the problem is whether add.d doesn't work correctly or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syscall 6 reads single precision floats. If you're going to add doubles, either convert your single precision values to doubles first with `cvt.d.s`, or switch to using syscalls 7 (read double) and 3 (print double).

Comment: Actually I just solved it by using add.s $f12,$f4,$f6
add.s $f13,$f5,$f6 instead of add.d $f12,$f4,$f6, I get double precision but I don't understand why.

Comment: @Hooman Make sure your test cases include additions for which you can distinguish between a correctly performance 32 bit float addition and a correctly performed 64 bit float addition. There is a risk that you have switched to doing 32 bit addition consistently, which would give similar answers to consistently performed 64 bit addition in many cases, especially if you only display a few digits of the result.